# How to use PHP cookies to identify unregistered online shoppers?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm used to work with php sessions when users login. I'm trying to figure out how to identify shopping carts of visitors (unregistered users) by creating a random `user_id` and storing it in their cart but I'm not understanding the logic of cookies. I'm generating a cookie_value, a random number with `rand()`. Do I need to add `cookie.php` to every single page like I would with `session.php`?

**cookie.php**

```
<?php
$cookie_value =rand(10,100);
$cookie_name='new_user'.$cookie_value;
setcookie($cookie_name,$cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
$user_id=$cookie_value;
```

**product.php**

```
    if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
    include 'includes/cookie.php';
    }elseif(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
    include 'includes/session.php';
    }

    if(!empty($_POST)){ 
    if(isset($_POST['addCart'])){
    //insert product
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];  
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id']; 
    $quantity=$_POST['quantity']; 
    $product_price=$_POST['product_price']; 

     // prepare and bind
    $cart = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO shopping_cart 
   (user_id,product_id,quantity,amount) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    $cart->bind_param("iiis", $user_id,$product_id,$quantity,$product_price);
    $cart->execute();   

    if($cart){
      header('Location: cart.php');
      exit;
    }
    $cart->close();
    $db->close();

   } }
```

Comment: In your user_id column, are you storing both the logged in user's id and the randomly generated id from your cookies to identify and retrieve carts?

Comment: @Yolo: No I dont. I just want to display a visitors cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question if you need to include cookies.php on every page, yes. Your cookie setting is going to cause trouble through, or at least if you use more that one cookie (maybe even those you are unaware of). If your cookie name is random, how are you going to retrieve it *easily*?

You should not concatenate the random value to form the cookie name. So the lines should be changed like so:

```
$cookie_value =rand(10,100); // sure about only 90 users??
$cookie_name='tmp_user_id'; // maybe temporary user is a more appropriate naming
if(!isset($_COOKIE['tmp_user_id']) && !isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
    setcookie($cookie_name,$cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
}
```

That way you can retrieve it in your scripts like so:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['tmp_user_id'])) {
    $user_id = $_COOKIE['tmp_user_id'];
}
```

**EDIT**

As Sebastian pointed out in the comment, you should check obviously if the cookie is set. So if cookie and user session is not set, set cookie. If your session setting procedure should reside in session.php include cookie.php thereafter.

Comment: By including cookie.php on every page, doesn't it create a new random number every time?

Comment: On cart.php I'm using this query to get visitors cart : SELECT * FROM shopping_cart WHERE user_id='$user_id' but the problem is the cookie is randomized... The number changes and I cant retrieve the cart. But I cant set same cookie for every visitor if I want to identify which cart belongs to which visitors. Does it make sense?

Comment: @SebastianFarham thanks for pointing that out. I adapted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are over-complicating thing a lot. PHP Sessions already do what you want. In fact they are meant specifically to solve this problem.

By default PHP Sessions use cookies to maintain state between requests and assign each user a unique SESSION_ID that you can read from your script. So there is no need for you to set an additional cookie.  Your code could be as simple as:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) $user_id = $_SESSION['logged_user'];    
else $user_id = session_id();// id sticks because it was stored in a cookie by PHP
```

Now you can use this `$user_id` to store or retrieve cart data from the DB. In fact, if you're dealing with a user who has not logged in, you could even just store the cart data in `$_SESSION`, so you won't bloat your DB with non-member data.

See the docs: [session_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php)